# R For Loop Append Dataframe Iterations to Empty Matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, combinations

I am trying to create an empty matrix and fill it with iterations of a dataframe. Using the below code:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:10), col2 = letters[1:10])
var <- seq(-.25,.25,.05)
var <- var[var != 0]

output <- matrix(ncol=ncol(df)+1, nrow=nrow(df)*length(var))

for(i in 1:length(var)){
  output[i,] <- df %>% mutate(var = df$col1*var[i])
}
```

With this code, I receive the following error message: incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Does anyone know what the issue could be? My desired output is for each value in col1 of df to be multiplied times each value in list var.

Thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a for-loop, but is this what you wanted for output?

```r
library(dplyr,warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:10), col2 = letters[1:10])
var <- seq(-.25,.25,.05)
var <- var[var != 0]

output <- matrix(ncol=ncol(df)+1, nrow=nrow(df)*length(var))

lapply(1:length(var), function(i) {
  x <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(var = col1*var[i]) %>%
    bind_rows()
}) %>% bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 100 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     col1 col2    var
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     1 a     -0.25
#>  2     2 b     -0.5 
#>  3     3 c     -0.75
#>  4     4 d     -1   
#>  5     5 e     -1.25
#>  6     6 f     -1.5 
#>  7     7 g     -1.75
#>  8     8 h     -2   
#>  9     9 i     -2.25
#> 10    10 j     -2.5 
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes that is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To create the 100 row data frame of col1, col2, var

```
var <- sapply(var, function(x) x * col1)
var <- as.vector(var)
col1 <- rep(col1, 10)
col2 <- rep(letters[1:10], 10)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, var)
df
    col1 col2   var
1      1    a -0.25
2      2    b -0.50
3      3    c -0.75
4      4    d -1.00
5      5    e -1.25
6      6    f -1.50
7      7    g -1.75
8      8    h -2.00
9      9    i -2.25
10    10    j -2.50
```

Comment: The resulting dataframe should be 100 rows (iterating through each row of col1 10 times (once for each value in vector var).

Comment: You lost me.  The 'length(var)' = 10.  So the loop is from 1 to 10.  See the updated answer.

Comment: The resulting dataframe output should have 3 columns and 100 rows. 1st column = each value from col1 of df repeated 10X, 2nd column = each value from col2 of df repeated 10X, 3rd column = each value of vector Var repeated 10X. Does that make sense?

Comment: 3rd column = each value of vector Var repeated 10X.  You lost me again.  You don't want `df$col1*var[i])`?

Comment: See below answer from Andrew Brown. That is the desired output.

Comment: see `sapply` added.